# Question regarding unexpected hanging paradox

Tags: logic, paradoxes

**The following is the unexpected hanging paradox:**

A judge tells a condemned prisoner that he will be hanged at noon on one weekday in the following week but that the execution will be a surprise to the prisoner. He will not know the day of the hanging until the executioner knocks on his cell door at noon that day.

Having reflected on his sentence, the prisoner draws the conclusion that he will escape from the hanging. His reasoning is in several parts. He begins by concluding that the "surprise hanging" can't be on Friday, as if he hasn't been hanged by Thursday, there is only one day left - and so it won't be a surprise if he's hanged on Friday. Since the judge's sentence stipulated that the hanging would be a surprise to him, he concludes it cannot occur on Friday.

He then reasons that the surprise hanging cannot be on Thursday either, because Friday has already been eliminated and if he hasn't been hanged by Wednesday night, the hanging must occur on Thursday, making a Thursday hanging not a surprise either. By similar reasoning he concludes that the hanging can also not occur on Wednesday, Tuesday or Monday. Joyfully he retires to his cell confident that the hanging will not occur at all.

The next week, the executioner knocks on the prisoner's door at noon on Wednesday — which, despite all the above, was an utter surprise to him. Everything the judge said came true.

**Observations**

In my opinion the above reasoning is a case of a "proof by assumption" with extra steps. Here's why:

1. prisoner assumes hanging didn't occur on Monday, ..., Thursday to
   conclude that it can't happen on Friday
2. he works backwards from Thursday to Monday using the same argument as for Friday

The second step is redundant since we already established in step 1, that hanging did  not occur on Mon, ..., Thu.

In this way, the "paradox" is reduced to a single implication: (no hanging Mon, ..., Thu) -> (no hanging on Fri). It's easy to agree with and not a paradox.

Is my thinking correct here?

Comment: The weak point of this paradox is that the prisoner will actually NOT be surprised , IF he/she expects the hanging (on every day) . But if the prisoner falls into the trap you described, then, he/she will be surprised. I think this is the actual intent of the paradox.

Comment: Prisoner can avoid being surprised by expecting to be hanged on every day - OK. If he convinces himself not to be surprised (by any reasoning), then he can be surprised, because judge can model his reasoning and counter it. Where's the paradox here?

Comment: The "rules" are clear, so the judge has not many options. He has to hang the prisoner on one of the five days, unless he lies and doesn't hang the prisoner at all or later, but this has nothing to do with the paradox.

Comment: @zxc Assuming something only temporarily allows us to treat it as "established". In step 1, $A$ is assumed and then we derive $B$, we can then conclude $A\to B$. At this point and in step 2, $A$ is no longer being assumed. Establishing $A\to B$ does not establish $A$.